# hive hql comparing values in case statements

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a query where i am trying to compare values in a case statement and if its less keep the value if its less make it null. I am getting the error

```
 SemanticException [Error 10128]:  Not yet supported place for UDAF 'max'

select mt.column1,   
min (case
    when mt2.number = 1  then mt.column2 end) as first_column,
max (case
    when mt2.number = 1  then mt.column2 end) as first_column_max,
min (case
    when mt2.number = 2 then mt.column2 end) as second_column,
max (case
    when mt2.number = 2 then mt.column2 end) as second_column_max,
min (case
    when mt2.number = 3 and mt.column2 > max (case
    when mt2.number = 1  then mt.column2 end) and  mt.column2 > 
       max (case
    when mt2.number = 2 then mt.column2 end) then mt.column2 else '' end) as third_column 
from mytable2 mt2
```

Comment: sample data and the expected results would help us understand what you are trying to do

Comment: do you have space after the max and min?